# Calculating the Ricci tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

I am currently working through an exercise to calculate the component $R_{22}$ of the Ricci tensor for the line element $ds^2=a^2dt^2 -a^2dx^2 - \frac{a^2e^{2x}}{2}dy^2 +2a^2e^xdydt -a^2dz^2$. The question first asks for the value of $\Gamma^{0}_{12}$, which I calculate to be $\frac{e^{x}}{2}$. I am told to assume the following values for the connection coefficients: $\Gamma^{0}_{12}=\Gamma^{0}_{21}=\Gamma^{0}_{10}=\Gamma^{0}_{01}=1$, $\Gamma^{1}_{22}=\frac{e^{2x}}{2}$, $\Gamma^{2}_{10}=-e^{-x}$, $\Gamma^{1}_{02}=\Gamma^{1}_{20}=\frac{e^{x}}{2}$ and all others are zero.

Using the relation for the Ricci tensor, I find that the only non-zero components are: $R_{22}=\partial_1(\Gamma^{0}_{12})+\Gamma^{0}_{10}\Gamma^{1}_{22}-\Gamma^{0}_{21}\Gamma^{1}_{02}-\Gamma^{1}_{20}\Gamma^{0}_{12}$. This is where the problem arises: using the assumed values for the connection coefficients (with $\Gamma^{0}_{12}=\Gamma^{0}_{21}=1$) I find that $R_{22}=e^{2x}-e^{x}$, while using the values $\Gamma^{0}_{12}=\Gamma^{0}_{21}=\frac{e^{x}}{2}$ (the rest being those assumed) I find that $R_{22}=e^{2x}$. I am told that the second result is correct. It seems to be the case that the assumed value for $\Gamma^{0}_{12}$ is incorrect.

Could someone provide clarification as to whether there is indeed a mistake in the question? As a beginner in GR, I find myself questioning the basics.

EDIT:

There was a mistype in the above metric the correct one should be: $ds^2=a^2dt^2 -a^2dx^2 + \frac{a^2e^{2x}}{2}dy^2 +2a^2e^xdydt -a^2dz^2$

This then gives:

$$g_{ab} = \left[\begin{matrix}a^{2} & 0 & a^{2} e^{x} & 0\\0 & - a^{2} & 0 & 0\\a^{2} e^{x} & 0 & + \frac{a^{2} e^{2 x}}{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & - a^{2}\end{matrix}\right]$$

and $$g^{ab} = \frac{1}{a^2}\left[\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 & 2 e^{-x} & 0\\0 & - 1 & 0 & 0\\ 2e^{-x} & 0 & -2e^{-2x} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & - 1\end{matrix}\right]$$

Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: I checked with a computer program and i arrive at the same Christoffel symbols as Kurt G. does. The coefficients of the Ricci tensor should be $$R_{\mu \nu } = \left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{e^{x}}{3} & 0 \\ 0 & - \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0\\  \frac{e^{x}}{3} & 0 & - \frac{2 e^{2 x}}{3} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: Would it be possible to recheck this using the corrected metric (see edits)? Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: With the updated metric the non zero Christoffel should be $\Gamma^0_{01} =\Gamma^0_{10}=1$, $\Gamma^0_{12} = \Gamma^0_{21}= \Gamma^1_{02} = \Gamma^1_{20} = \frac{e^{x}}{2}$, $\Gamma^1_{22} = \frac{e^{2 x}}{2}$ and $\Gamma^2_{01} = \Gamma^2_{10} =- e^{- x}$. The Ricci tensor is $$R_{\mu \nu} = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & e^{x} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\e^{x} & 0 & e^{2 x} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: Thanks. As a final question would you then say the assumption that $\Gamma^{0}_{12} = 1$ is incorrect? I think the idea was that the component $R_{22}$
 was supposed to be $e^{2x}$
 either way. Though this doesn't seem to be work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the below `python` code the metric
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}a^{2} & 0 & a^{2} e^{x} & 0\\0 & - a^{2} & 0 & 0\\a^{2} e^{x} & 0 &  \frac{a^{2} e^{2 x}}{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & - a^{2}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
has the following Christoffel symbols ${\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\rho}$ of the second kind ${\Gamma^0}_{\nu\rho},{\Gamma^1}_{\nu\rho},{\Gamma^2}_{\nu\rho},{\Gamma^3}_{\nu\rho}$:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & \frac{e^{x}}{2} & 0\\0 & \frac{e^{x}}{2} & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right],
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & \frac{e^{x}}{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\frac{e^{x}}{2} & 0 & \frac{e^{2 x}}{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right],
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & - e^{- x} & 0 & 0\\- e^{- x} & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right],
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}
The Ricci tensor is
\begin{align}
R_{\mu\nu}=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & e^{x} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\e^{x} & 0 & e^{2 x} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

```
# https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~hanauske/VARTC/VARTCorona/python/GraviPy-tutorial.html

from gravipy.tensorial import *
from sympy import init_printing, pprint, print_latex, exp
import inspect
init_printing()


a, t, x, y, z, M = symbols('a t, x, y, z, M')

# create a coordinate four-vector object instantiating 
# the Coordinates class
C = Coordinates('\chi', [t, x, y, z])
# define a matrix of a metric tensor components
Metric = Matrix([[a**2,0,a**2*exp(x),0],[0,-a**2,0,0],[a**2*exp(x),0,a**2*exp(2*x)/2,0],[0,0,0,-a**2]])
print_latex( Metric )
# create a metric tensor object instantiating the MetricTensor class
g = MetricTensor('g', C, Metric)
Ga = Christoffel('Ga', g)
#for i in [1,2,3,4]: # first kind
#    print_latex( Ga(i,All,All) )
for i in [-1,-2,-3,-4]: # second kind
    print_latex( Ga(i,All,All) )
```

Comment: Would it be possible to recheck this using the corrected metric (see edits)? Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: @jore1 Sure. In no time when I am back at the computer having that little python program. I was surprised how simple it was to set it up. Python is for free. Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\Gamma^0_{12} = \frac 12 g^{0a}(\partial_1g_{a2} + \partial_2g_{a1} - \partial_ag_{12})$.

We have that $g_{ab} = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 & 0 & a^2 e^x &  0 \\ 0 & -a^2 & 0 & 0 \\ a^2 e^x & 0 & -\frac 12 a^2e^{2x} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -a^2\end{pmatrix}$.

We can invert the $[2\times 2]$ matrix for $g_{00}, g_{02},g_{20},g_{22}$ by hand to avoid looking up how to invert a full $4\times 4$ matrix.

This gives us that $g^{00} = \frac 13 a^{-2}$ and $g^{02} = a^{-2}\frac 23 e^{-x}$.

Finally with $a=0,2$ being the only two non-zero terms in the Christoffel summation we get: $\Gamma^0_{12} = \frac 12 (\frac 13 a^{-2}(a^2 e^x) + a^{-2}\frac 23 e^{-x} (-a^2 e^{2x}) )  = \frac 12 (\frac 13 e^x - \frac 23 e^x) = - \frac 16 e^x$. This agrees with Kurt G.

Comment: Would it be possible to recheck this using the corrected metric (see edits)? Apologies for the mistake. I have also included the inverse metric now.

Comment: I think better to go with Kurt's answer, as will do the algebra for you. This answer is to provide some mathematical details of the calculation. The exact numbers are not relevant for future users.